# List all Files of directory in PhoneGap IOS

Tags: json, cordova

I need to generate a list of files in a directory, and then generate a file with these. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checkout `DirectoryReader` provided by cordova. `DirectorReader` object lists files and directories within a directory.

```
function success(entries) {
    var i;
    for (i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
        console.log('En - ', entries[i]);
    }
}
function fail(error) {
    console.log("Failed to list directory contents: ", error);
}

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(DIR_FULL_PATH, function(dirEntry) {
    var directoryReader = dirEntry.createReader();
    console.log(dirEntry);

    // Get a list of all the entries in the directory
    directoryReader.readEntries(success,fail);
});
```

Here is the [LINK](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#DirectoryReader) for more details.

Another link [Mobile File Explorer with PhoneGap/Cordova](http://www.digitalnoiz.com/mobile-development/mobile-file-explorer-with-phonegapcordova-and-jquery-mobile-part-1/) has examples.

Cheers !!

Comment: is just in this line "var directoryReader = dirEntry.createReader();
" when my code is broken

Comment: You can create entry using constructor `var dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(name, path);`

Comment: sorry for my insistence but I can not run the DirectoryEntry. 

Might give me an example to list all files of the WWW Folder

Comment: Please check second link in my answer.